Are smaller wind instruments harder to play in tune than larger instruments of the same family?
I've seen people claim that the A♭ clarinet is pickier about intonation than the E♭ clarinet, which, in turn, is pickier than the B♭ clarinet; that the soprillo and the sopranino saxophones are extremely difficult to control and it's recommended to learn to control the soprano saxophone before even trying; that soprano recorders are less forgiving and harder to play in tune than alto recorders.
Is this generally true for all wind instruments and, if it is, why?

Well, a small identical change on the mouth will have a bigger relative impact on smaller instrument, the same way that changing a meter in a km rope is negligible, but maybe not in a three meters one. Will try to elaborate, if time allows.

Piccolo is fickler than flute for sure!

Wondering about the clarinet order; putting bass clarinet and exotic instruments aside, A♭ is the lowest and E♭ the highest?

@guidot A♭ is the highest, and very rare.

@PiedPiper: I had supposed, A was intended as somewhat common variant.

Sounds very logical, and very likely the same for strings.
As I said in my comment, all is about relatives: small instruments work on higher frequencies, which in turn, are smaller wavelengths. This means that the differences of the length of the air column between two adjacent notes is smaller. (Note that it is the same on strings, that's why frets are getting closer apart on a guitar, the higher you go).
It follows that on small instruments, a small variation of the air column length (and on strings, a small variation of the free-length of the string) will have a greater impact than for big instruments. To be precise, the same variation will have a relative bigger impact, hence the need to be more precise in order to get a good intonation. Basically, on a meter sized column, a change of a centimetre does not bring you as close to the next note than the same change on a 10 cm column.

Think about percentages - on an instrument that is several meters long (tuba say), if you move its tuning slide by 10 mm, that's a smaller percentage overall length change than if you move the tuning slide on a trumpet or piccolo trumpet by 10 mm.

You're right about strings, people also seem to say that the violin is harder to play in tune than the cello: https://www.violinist.com/discussion/archive/10251/

This is in addition to Tom's answer.
Although I am not certain, I imagine that the perception of pitch also influences the matter a little bit. My understanding is that the perception of note intervals changes between high and low frequencies. Our human ears perceive the same note interval (such as a semi-tone) to be larger between high notes than between low notes. As stated on the Wikipedia page of the Mel scale:

Above about 500 Hz, increasingly large intervals are judged by listeners to produce equal pitch increments.

So, on top of the fact that the same absolute deviation in length will have a greater relative impact on high notes, as Tom stated, the same relative deviation in note intervals will also have a bigger impact on high notes because we are more sensitive in this area.

It looks as though the MEL scale research is not universally accepted among experts. This shouldn't detract though from the (very likely) possibility that the human ear's sensitivity to small tuning errors varies with pitch.

Certainly as a trained musician, I would perceive a semitone to be a semitone no matter what the pitch, and I would also regard the number of semitones as the obvious measure of "distance between pitches". I would accept that someone with no musical training might disagree though.

None of this is to be confused with the fact that musical pitch follows an exponential (non-linear) scale with respect to frequency.

I understand the quote in exactly the opposite way: for hight notes, larger intervals produce the same percieved pitch increments, hence, the same interval would be percieved to be smaller between high notes.
